# Question of the Week (Jan 2017 #1)

Tags: discussion, fun, question-of-the-week

It's time to choose a [Question of the Week](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8359)! The Question of the Week demonstrates what a good on-topic question looks like.

Suggest the next Question of the Week by answering here with a link to the question, and a short explanation why it's an exemplary on topic question. You may suggest [any question that was posted between 2017-01-01 and 2017-01-07 and is not closed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20created%3a2017-01-01..2017-01-07%20closed%3ano%20score%3a1).

Select the next Question of the Week by upvoting and downvoting suggestions. Ask yourself:

1. Is this question firmly and unambiguously within the scope of Software Engineering?
2. Is this an interesting and well-written question?
3. Would I like to see more questions like that?

The next QotW will be the suggestion with the highest score by next week. If you have doubts about a suggestion, you can discuss it in the comments.

Comment: So lets give it a try, to see how this works.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Which should be done first: use cases or user stories?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/339568/60357)

Here, the asker is trying to find a good way to capture their requirements, for the special case of a solo developer.

We don't do recommendations. But explaining how a technique can fit into a development process is perfectly on topic. In particular, I'd like to see more questions on requirements engineering around here :)

Answer (score 5):

### [Strategies for merging 1 year of development in Visual Studio](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/339358)

This is about a real-world problem the OP faces, not a question for a hypothetical or upcoming scenario, and it is clearly located in the domain of software engineering. Though some tools are mentioned, the question is mostly independent from the specific version control system, so it is really a conceptual and organizational question.

Answer (score 4):

### [Agile stabilization and release management](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/339244/60357)

In this question, a rather waterfally organization is trying to go Agile. How do we structure our team? How do we deal with technical debt and maintenance work?

Questions [about](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/help/on-topic) the software-development life cycle (and ways to master it) are at the core of Software Engineering, and I think this question is a nice example of that.