# Vote for the Question of the Week! (Jan 2017 #2)

Tags: discussion, fun, question-of-the-week

It's time to choose a [Question of the Week](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8359)! The Question of the Week demonstrates what a good on-topic question looks like. [Last week](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8380/), we picked:

[*Which should be done first: use cases or user stories?* by user1620696](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/339568/)

**Suggest the next Question of the Week** by answering here with a link to the question, and a short explanation why it's an exemplary on topic question. You may suggest [any question that was posted between 2017-01-08 and 2017-01-14 and is not closed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20created%3a2017-01-08..2017-01-14%20closed%3ano%20score%3a1).

**Select the next Question of the Week** by upvoting and downvoting suggestions. Ask yourself:

1. Is this question firmly and unambiguously within the scope of Software Engineering?
2. Is this an interesting and well-written question?
3. Would I like to see more questions like that?

The next QotW will be the suggestion with the highest score by next week. If you have doubts about a suggestion, you can discuss it in the comments.

Comment: Amon - no more than 7 upvotes to the first "question of the week" tells me there is far too few backup by the community. I think we should stop this.

Comment: @DocBrown There's not a lot of community interaction here, agreed. However, it passed my personal success metric of score ≥ 5 for the winning suggestion. I'm hesitant to draw conclusions from a single data point and want to run 4 QotW installments, then open a meta discussion on the future (switch to monthly?). Robert's original QotW post gathered substantial interest. Let's just see how this works out.

Comment: Note: **Upvote this meta question** to see more community involvement. Most users don't visit Meta but perhaps see the “Hot meta posts” box in the sidebar; currently a score of >4 would be needed to get a place there.

Comment: amon, consider posting comment like above ^^^ at every new QOTW. That is, until this experiment is matured to the stage when it would be okay to ask moderators tag it [meta-tag:featured] (I feel that it's not quite there yet but is very likely to get there in a month or two, so far QOTW seems to run really well)

Comment: @gnat Thanks, I will include such a call-to-action in the next instalments from the start. I looked at the featured-tag but don't think it would ever be a good idea to feature the QotW since it doesn't meet that level of importance. And if the QotW is popular it won't need to be featured, but if not it doesn't really deserve to be.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### [What is the importance of the vision document and how it helps development?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/340019/)

Most of our process-level questions are about “how do I agile?”. This question instead asks about *vision documents*, and how they assist in software development.

I like that OP seems to have done some prior research before asking here, and articulates what they do and don't understand so far – thus making it easier to provide a focussed answer.

Answer (score 3):

### [How do you deal with dependencies that require the object you inject into?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/340125/)

A wonderful design-level question that gets to the point: how does dependency injection work with circular references?

Answer (score 3):

### [How to describe the architecture of a software product?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/339864)

A great question. API-level documentation is easy, but how can I communicate an architecture?

While the question may seem basic, it is fiercely on-topic for Software Engineering. OP has (literally) done their homework before coming here. In its original form the question was a bit rambly, but I tried to edit that out.

Answer (score 2):

### [How do you develop software without acceptance criteria?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/339807/how-do-you-develop-software-without-acceptance-criteria)

Ok, it is arguable if this is a dupe (but since it was not closed after one week, I guess it is not "dupe enough". Nevertheless how to gather requirements, especially when your organization does not provide you with a useful spec, seems to be a topic in which our community is heavily interested here.