# Vote for the Question of the Week (Jan 2017 #3)

Tags: discussion, fun, question-of-the-week

It's time to choose a [Question of the Week](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8359)! The Question of the Week demonstrates what a good on-topic question looks like. [Last week](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8398/), we picked:

[*What is the importance of the vision document and how it helps development?* by user1620696](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/340019)

**Suggest the next Question of the Week** by answering here with a link to the question, and a short explanation why it's an exemplary on topic question. You may suggest [any question that was posted between 2017-01-15 and 2017-01-21 and is not closed](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20created%3a2017-01-15..2017-01-21%20closed%3ano%20score%3a1).

**Select the next Question of the Week** by upvoting and downvoting suggestions. Ask yourself:

1. Is this question firmly and unambiguously within the scope of Software Engineering?
2. Is this an interesting and well-written question?
3. Would I like to see more questions like that?

The next QotW will be the suggestion with the highest score by next sunday. If you have doubts about a suggestion, you can discuss it in the comments.

**Vote for this meta question** if you like the Question of the Week idea, and want to see more community involvement. Most users don't visit meta, but perhaps see the “hot meta posts” in the community bulletin on the right.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

### [Is there a programming paradigm that promotes making dependencies extremely obvious to other programmers?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/340356)

This question rescues itself from being yet another "Name that Thing" question, because it touches on a topic that I consider extremely important, an issue that we've all been affected by, but which is seldom talked about: **how do you make sure that your system can be understood by others, and what provides the incentives for making that happen?**

It eloquently articulates the OP's frustrations without being a rant, provides a practical example of the problem, and leaves the door open for solutions beyond "name that paradigm."

Answer (score 6):

### [How to specify a precondition (LSP) in an interface in C#?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/340316/60357)

A nice design-level question. OP is trying to map some constraints into the C# type system (though the same problem arises in Java, C++, …). They have tried various solutions and explain their thoughts in the question. Instead of weighing down the helpful code examples with unnecessary implementation details, everything stays on the design level that is on topic here – a great example how such questions should be asked.

Answer (score 3):

### [RESTful API and i18n: how to design the response?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/340469/60357)

A design level question on designing a RESTful API. Normally, content negotiation is done to decide on a *single* representation of some resource, but here OP needs a mechanism to request *all* representations.

As in any good design question, OP has thought of possible solutions before asking here and explains them. This avoids answers with something OP already knows, and helps to reveal possible misunderstanding of underlying concepts.

While the question happens to ask “which is best?”, it is clearly not an opinion poll as it provides enough context for an objective answer.