# Vote for the Question of the Week! (Feb 2017 #1)

Tags: discussion, fun, question-of-the-week

It's time to choose a [Question of the Week](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8359)! The Question of the Week demonstrates what a good on-topic question looks like. [Last week](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8423), we picked:

- [*How to correct a mistake in the test, after writing implementation* by Attilio](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/341138)

**Suggest the next Question of the Week** by answering here with a link to the question, and a short explanation why it's an exemplary on topic question. You may suggest any question that was posted between 2017-01-29 and 2017-02-04 and is not closed. You can **[use this search query](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20created%3a2017-01-29..2017-02-04%20closed%3ano%20score%3a1)** to quickly find promising candidates.

**Vote on suggestions** to select the next Question of the Week. Ask yourself:

1. Is this question firmly and unambiguously within the scope of Software Engineering?
2. Is this an interesting and well-written question?
3. Would I like to see more questions like that?

The next QotW will be the suggestion with the highest score by next Sunday. If you have doubts about a suggestion, you can discuss it in the comments.

**Vote for this meta question** if you like the Question of the Week contest. This makes the contest more visible in the community bulletin on the right. Please also look at the [Question of the Week Evaluation](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8434) where we discuss whether this contest should be continued, and what could be improved.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

### [Python - Architecture for related instance attributes](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/341260/60357)

A design level question. It's a bit long to summarize here, but OP does a superb job of showing possible solutions which they tried, and how these are unsatisfactory solutions to the problem. I wish every question here was as well thought out!

Answer (score 0):

### [When to use a static method instead of a constructor?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/341545/60357)

A very good design-level question with regard to single-method objects: If an object is essentially just a function, when should I pass any arguments as arguments to the function (`new F().call(args)`), and when should I store the arguments as fields through the constructor (`new F(args).call()`)?