# Vote for the Question of the Week! (Feb 2017 #2)

Tags: discussion, fun, question-of-the-week

It's time to choose a [Question of the Week](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8359)! The Question of the Week demonstrates what a good on-topic question looks like. [Last week](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8435), we picked:

- [*Python - Architecture for related instance attributes* by John T](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/341260)

**Suggest the next Question of the Week**: just [pick a good question from this search query](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20created%3a2017-02-05..2017-02-11%20closed%3ano%20score%3a1) and post the link as an answer. If you want to, add a short explanation why the suggested question is great.

**Vote on suggestions** to select the next Question of the Week. Ask yourself:

1. Is this question firmly and unambiguously within the scope of Software Engineering?
2. Is this an interesting and well-written question?
3. Would I like to see more questions like that?

The next QotW will be the suggestion with the highest score by next Sunday. If you have doubts about a suggestion, you can discuss it in the comments.

**Vote for this meta question** if you like the Question of the Week contest. This makes the contest more visible in the community bulletin on the right. Please also look at the [Question of the Week Evaluation](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8434) where we discuss whether this contest should be continued, and what could be improved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [How do I handle disagreement in a code review regarding an unlikely edge case?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/341576/9113)

Code reviews and decisions which edge cases to handle in unit tests are clearly within the scope, the question is well written, and it is not a hypothetical case but a problem from a real-world situation. Moreover, the number of votes for the question as well as for the answers show our community likes to see more questions of this kind.

Answer (score 2):

### [Anemic REST and DDD](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/341782/60357)

A design-level question. How fine-grained should our URL structure be when designing a REST API?

Answer (score 2):

### [WHEN is it most appropriate for a Development Team to create/update their definition of “Done”?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/341977/60357)

A process-level question. Very simple but also very important. I think this kind of question is a perfect example of the “Wiki” aspect in the original Stack Exchange concept.