# Vote for the Question of the Week! (Feb 2017 #3)

Tags: discussion, fun, question-of-the-week

It's time to choose a [Question of the Week](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8359)! The Question of the Week demonstrates what a good on-topic question looks like. [Last week](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8442), we picked:

- [*How do I handle disagreement in a code review regarding an unlikely edge case?* by Klik](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/341576)

**Suggest the next Question of the Week**: just [pick a good question from this search query](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20created%3a2017-02-12..2017-02-18%20closed%3ano%20score%3a1) and post the link as an answer. If you want to, add a short explanation why the suggested question is great.

**Vote on suggestions** to select the next Question of the Week. Ask yourself:

1. Is this question firmly and unambiguously within the scope of Software Engineering?
2. Is this an interesting and well-written question?
3. Would I like to see more questions like that?

The next QotW will be the suggestion with the highest score by next Sunday. If you have doubts about a suggestion, you can discuss it in the comments.

**Vote for this meta question** if you like the Question of the Week contest. This makes the contest more visible in the community bulletin on the right. Please also look at the [Question of the Week Evaluation](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8434) where we discuss whether this contest should be continued, and what could be improved.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

### [Effectively tracking changes to configuration from dev to prod](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/342462/effectively-tracking-changes-to-configuration-from-dev-to-prod)

Clearly a "Systems Lifecycle" question, which needs combined organizational and technical measures, so undoubtly within the site's scope. Also a "real life" situation - I have encountered these kind of questions multiple times in the past, and I guess others, too. So I am a bit astonished the question did not get more attention last week - maybe it will get by my suggestion for the QotW here.

Answer (score 3):

### [Should every method return a value for Unit Testing?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/342263/60357)

This question is about adapting a design for testability. But it turns out to be a bit of an XY-problem. Since OP has provided a couple of code snippets for context and has expressed their *intention*, the answers were able to point out that the “system under test” doesn't just have to be a single method.