# Vote for the Question of the Week! (Feb 2017 #4)

Tags: discussion, fun, question-of-the-week

It's time to choose a Question of the Week! The Question of the Week demonstrates what a good on-topic question looks like. [Last week](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8455), we picked:

- [*Effectively tracking changes to configuration from dev to prod* by Mathieu Fortin](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/342462)

**Suggest the next Question of the Week**: just [pick a good question from this search query](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/search?tab=votes&q=is%3aquestion%20created%3a2017-02-19..2017-02-25%20closed%3ano%20score%3a1) and post the link as an answer. If you want to, add a short explanation why the suggested question is great.

**Vote on suggestions** to select the next Question of the Week. Ask yourself:

1. Is this question firmly and unambiguously within the scope of Software Engineering?
2. Is this an interesting and well-written question?
3. Would I like to see more questions like that?

The next QotW will be the suggestion with the highest score by next Sunday. If you have doubts about a suggestion, you can discuss it in the comments.

**Vote for this meta question** if you like the Question of the Week contest. This makes the contest more visible in the community bulletin on the right. Please also look at the [Question of the Week Evaluation](https://softwareengineering.meta.stackexchange.com/q/8434) where we discuss whether this contest should be continued, and what could be improved.

Answer (score 3):

### [Writing tests for code whose purpose I don't understand](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/questions/342824/writing-tests-for-code-whose-purpose-i-dont-understand)

IMHO the best questions here are ones which arise from real world software development situations, and this one fits perfectly into this category. Testing and refactoring is clearly and unambiguously within the scope of the site. And the number of votes shows many people here like questions like this.

Answer (score 2):

### [How to convert the last rc (or other pre-release) into the production version using semver?](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/342808/60357)

A process-level question: Now that I've built and tested v1.2.3-rc.2 of my software, how do I turn that into my v1.2.3 release?

Answer (score 1):

### [Requirement Specification - How to write an “as much as possible” requisite](https://softwareengineering.stackexchange.com/q/342743/60357)

Not everything is a clear functional requirement. So how can I express and track soft design constraints?